# Update Event on Custom Binding Not Triggered

Tags: knockout.js, updatemodel, custom-binding

this is my html :
Hi, Guys,

I am new bie on knockoutjs world, but i am feeling very interested to use it in my next project because it seems it is a powerfull framework. But i a having some obstacles to understand on how the knockoutjs custom binding works because i was fail to make it works on my own codes. So actually i did some small experiment on my own like the codes below:

This my code on my html file:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div data-bind="schoolCalendar: student">        
</div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: change" value="Click"/>
</form>
```

this is my javascript :

```
    var student = function (firstname, lastname, age) {
        self = this;
        self.firstname = ko.observable(firstname);
        self.lastname = ko.observable(lastname);
        self.age = ko.observable(age);
    }

    var model = function (student) {
        self = this;
        self.student = ko.observable(student);
        self.change = function () {
            self.student.firstname = "Virna";
            self.student.lastname = "Patel";
            self.student.age = 27;
        };
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.schoolCalendar = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
            var root = $(element);
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var html = "<span id=\"firstname\">Firstname is " + valueUnwrapped.firstname() + "</span><br/>";
            html += "<span id=\"lastname\">Lastname is " + valueUnwrapped.lastname() + "</span><br/>";
            html += "<span id=\"age\">Age is " + valueUnwrapped.age() + "</span><br/>";
            root.append(html);

            ko.applyBindingsToNode($("firstname").get(0), valueUnwrapped.firstname());
            ko.applyBindingsToNode($("lastname").get(0), valueUnwrapped.lastname());
            ko.applyBindingsToNode($("age").get(0), valueUnwrapped.age());

            return ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var m = new model(new student("John", "Hadikusumo", 43));
        ko.applyBindings(m);
    });
```

My question is : why when i click the button, it doesnt trigger the update event on knockoutjs bindingHandler. What did i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your custom handler isn't firing because your `model.change` function is not using the correct syntax for working with ko observables.  You need to use `()` when getting or setting their value.

```
self.change = function () {
            self.student().firstname("Virna");
            self.student().lastname("Patel");
            self.student().age(27);
        };
```

You may be able to do away with the custom binding handler altogether though.  You can accomplish the same functionality with the code below (no custom handler).  Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dcv/HBNac/19/)

HTML

```
<div data-bind="with: student">
    Firstname is <span id="firstname" data-bind="text: firstname"></span><br />
    Lastname is <span id="lastname" data-bind="text: lastname"></span><br />
    Age is <span id="age" data-bind="text: age"></span>
</div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: change" value="Click"/>
```

JS

```
var student = function (firstname, lastname, age) {
    self = this;
    self.firstname = ko.observable(firstname);
    self.lastname = ko.observable(lastname);
    self.age = ko.observable(age);
};

var model = function (std) {
    self = this;
    self.student = ko.observable(std);
    self.change = function () {
        self.student().firstname("Virna");
        self.student().lastname("Patel");
        self.student().age(27);
    };
};

var m = new model(new student("John", "Hadikusumo", 43));
ko.applyBindings(m);
```

Comment: i followed the changes you made on self.change but still not working. The changes doesn't trigger the update event on custom ko.bindingHandler.

Comment: @JohnHadikusumo Your bindingHandler is not triggered because it listening on `stundent` but the student object doesn't changed only its properties. You need to tell KO that is value is modified: `self.change = function () {
        self.student().firstname("Virna");
        self.student().lastname("Patel");
        self.student().age(27);
        self.student.valueHasMutated();
    };`

Comment: Just wierd, now the change event is not working either. What a life !